# Unable to create/find executable when using rosrun

Tags: moveit, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to run a C++ code to move the ur5 robotic arm to random configurations in moveit!. However when I am trying to run the code using rosrun I am getting the following error:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named move_group_interface_tutorial below /home/abhi/Desktop/universal_robot/ur_moveit_tutorials

The C++ file is this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "lesson_move_group");

  // start a background "spinner", so our node can process ROS messages
  //  - this lets us know when the move is completed
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("manipulator");
  group.setRandomTarget();
  group.move();
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt file is something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)



rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

rosbuild_add_executable(lesson_move_group_1 src/lesson_move_group_1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lesson_move_group_1 moveit_move_group_interface)
```

Please tell me how to create the executable and run this code. I am stuck here for quite some time now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175201/unable-to-create/find-executable-when-using-rosrun./) by [Abhishek Jha](https://answers.ros.org/users/18975/abhishek-jha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-27**:
can you please try to use the code tag (the button where the 1s and 0s are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this. I used the rosmake command.

$rosmake {package_name}

It helped create the executable and I was able to run it using rosrun.

---

Originally posted by [Abhishek Jha](https://answers.ros.org/users/18975/abhishek-jha/) with karma: 16 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-28**:
So what have you done before instead?

**Comment by [Abhishek Jha](https://answers.ros.org/users/18975/abhishek-jha/) on 2014-06-30**:
I was using cmake to build the packages. In that case I was not able to create the executable.